# Getting "UnrecognizedInputFormatException" with media3-exoplayer when streaming mp3 from onedrive

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, playback, android-media3

Very new to android programming, I am trying to implement media3-exoplayer in my app. I read the developer.adroid material and tried the basic scenario first but my mp3 wont play. Getting the below error everytime

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:652)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:622)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:94)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1018)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

here is my java code

```
audioURL = "https://1drv.ms/u/s!AinVIRl3CTeehK4nagw3kE9u9ArztA?e=Cvd4v3";

Uri audioUri = Uri.parse(audioURL);

exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

exoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.mediaPlayer);

// Bind the player to the view.
exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

// Build the media item.
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(audioUri);

// Set the media item to be played.
exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);

// Prepare the player.
exoPlayer.prepare();
// Start the playback.
exoPlayer.play();
```

I tried building diffenet media source (hls, progressive etc) instead of media item and setting the mediasource as well but nothing worked.
file is definately mp3 checked mutiple times to make sure.
mp3 link is directly copied from the share option in one drive

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix it by changing the url. Instead of share URL in One Drive I took the embed URL. In the URL made the following changes

- changed "/embed" to "/download"
- added "&play=1" at the end of URL to make sure it plays directly from server instead of downloading

after these changes, the error was gone and the player stared working.